# Payment Gateway integration in java for recurring billing without storing credit card information

Tags: java, paypal, payment-gateway, authorize.net

The situation which I need to address is, I need to integrate payment gateway on my J2EE web application which supports recurring billing facility without storing the credit card information on my site, please let me know the best way to solve this problem.

I have integrated Authorize.net Server Integration Method for making transaction, using which I am successfully able to complete transaction, without storing credit card information on my site, but in order to convert this transaction into a recurring billing subscription, I will have to store 
the credit card number information on my site, which is not as per PCI Compliance. So, in this case as well, what will be the best approach, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your previous transaction was successful, you can use [createCustomerProfileFromTransactionRequest](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#customer-profiles-create-a-customer-profile-from-a-transaction) to create a customer profile using the previous transaction id, and then use the customer profile with [ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#recurring-billing-create-a-subscription-from-customer-profile) to create a subscription.